# Distributions taking values in a TVS which is not locally convex

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, tempered-distributions

It seems to me that Schwartz's two seminal papers on vector-valued distributions only deals with distributions taking values in a locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space (LCS). Most other treatments (in books) refer to these two papers and many a time are only interested in the Banach space case.

1. *Is there a general notion of derivative for functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a Hausdorff TVS $V$ (**not** assumed to be locally convex)?*

In Lang's book on "Differential and Riemannian Geometry" (page 6), definition of tangent to 0 and derivative are given for maps between two LCS's (although the book says TVS, but the umbrella hypotheses laid out in the beginning of the chapter includes the assumption of local-convexity). Can't the same definition of derivatives be used for general TVS's?

2. *How far can we relax the local-convexity assumption and still have a reasonable theory of vector-valued distributions?* Could you please provide references where such an exploration is done?

My interest arises from the study of certain spaces which are (a type of) limits of Banach spaces but not necessarily locally convex.

Thank you.

Comment: The usual definition of the Fréchet derivative of a function between normed spaces makes sense for a functions from an open subset of a normed space $X$with values in a topological vector space $Y$: There is a continuous linear map $f'(x):X\to Y$ such that $(f(x)-f(y)-f'(x)(x-y))/\|x-y\| \to 0$ for $y\to x$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I guess that the problem is about the expected properties of derivatives. In particular, it seems to me that $Y$ should be reasonably complete, otherwise the analysis there might be pathological.

Comment: Completeness of $Y$ is one natural requirement. On the other hand, one of the priniple ideas of distribution theory is to use Hahn-Banach to obtain solutions of linear PDEs, e.g., fundamental solutions in the case of constant coefficients. A non-locallyconvex range is at least rather queer to that priciple.

Comment: You didn't give any clue of what kind of non-locally convex limit of Banach spaces, say $E$, you are considering. If $E$ has a point separating dual space, then there is some room for a reasonable theory of $E$−valued distributions although I do not know whether there is any published presentation of such. Bastiani's theory (J. Anal. Math., 1964) of differentiable maps between certain convergence vector (or rather, affine) spaces can be used as a basis for such a theory.